# How to find correct hook/preprocessor

Tags: 7, hooks, theming

Aside from searching [the Drupal api](http://api.drupal.org), is there a module or an easy way that will allow you to find out which hook or function you need to use to interact with pages in your site?

For example, I am looking to force certain values in a webform setup, to which I was able to use `mymodule_form_webform_configure_form_alter` to change the submission limit, status etc. But I was able to do this because I found the starting point for the script, now I am looking to force a default 'email to' value in the setup, but I don't know what function I need to use

What's the best way of finding out the best hook (etc..) for the job

Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

I find the [Devel Themer module](https://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) to be very helpful.

From the description:

> popup display shows which theme function/template outputted the HTML, and what other files could have done so.

Comment: I've been using the Devel Themer module at times, although I find it a little glitchy, and only shows you what you want to know half the time, but yes I agree you can use this module